# jQuery Slide In and Out Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm making a website for the first time. I'd like to start it with a Image Slider. I wanted to animate it. So I've just created a div and placed some `h1` and `span` tag with some text. I'd want to animate them to slide in from Top and sideways. I did google some thing about it but i'm not good in using `jquery-ui` and `css-transistions`. I'd like to animate the `h1` and `span` elements like the one in the below URL [**RENO HTML Template**](http://www.entiri.com/reno/). Any links to get the animations like that will help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="slideshow" align="center">
    <div id="black">
        <h1>Black</h1>
        <span>black</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQueryUI makes it really easy. You can try to do something in these lines:

```
$( document ).click(function() { // I put on click to visualize it, but you can do it on whatever event you like, mouseover, page load and so on
   $( "h1" ).toggle( "slide" , {
        direction: 'left' 
    }, 500); // You can specify how fast you want your animation to be, the unit is milliseconds
});
```

As to answer the comment, here an alternative for sliding on document ready ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/93mzw/)):

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow" align="center">
    <div id="black">
        <h1>Black</h1>
        <span>black</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#black {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -250px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

JS

```
$("h1").animate({
   "top":"0px"
},1200);
```

Comment: Hey Thomas - I'm sorry, that didn't help me. And i want to slide in the `h1` element from the top not the whole div.

Comment: Thanks it helped me thomas. Thanks a lot. But when i change the direction to top or bottom. It's starting from the right. How do i do it? And i don't want to toggle it. I want that to happen when the page is loaded. How can I call it in that case?

Comment: It's even easier, I updated the comment. Simply put the jQuery code inside ```$(document).ready()```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simplest attempt at trying to explain how jQuery can help:

First, you want to find your element(s). This can be done using:

```
$('name');
```

Insert # for ids and . for classes

If you want to get the children of your div with an id of black, for example, do this:

```
$('#black').children();
```

Then, you can animate then given a certain action:

```
$('#black').children().on('click', function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```

The `this` will act on the element you get using the line you used to find your element. Then simply call slideUp() on it to make it slide up. And there are several other alternatives to click.

Search how you'd include jQuery, and make sure you write this code in a separate .js file.

Comment: Hi Marcel - Thanks for the reply. But that didn't help me out. I've tried with your function. I can see nothing happening to the elements.

Comment: forgot one thing - make sure you put this in a `$(document).ready(function() { ...all of this code... });` That way this code runs once the document has loaded. And obviously because the function is in a `click` listener, this will happen when you click the h1/span.